# Faraday JSON post 'undefined method bytesize' for has bodies

Tags: ruby, faraday

I'm trying to convert some code from `HTTParty` to `Faraday`. Previously I was using:

```
HTTParty.post("http://localhost/widgets.json", body: { name: "Widget" })
```

The new snippet is:

```
faraday = Faraday.new(url: "http://localhost") do |config|
  config.adapter Faraday.default_adapter

  config.request :json
  config.response :json
end
faraday.post("/widgets.json", { name: "Widget" })
```

Which results in: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'bytesize' for {}:Hash`. Is it possible to have Faraday automatically serialize my request body into a string?

Comment: Try putting adapter last in the middleware list — see [Advanced middleware usage](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

Comment: @l'L'l That is definitely the bug. Can you add an answer instead of a comment so I can accept + bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The middleware list requires it be constructed/stacked in a particular order, otherwise you'll encounter this error. The first middleware is considered the outermost, which wraps all others, so the adapter should be the innermost one (or last):

```
Faraday.new(url: "http://localhost") do |config|
  config.request :json
  config.response :json
  config.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

See [Advanced middleware usage](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#advanced-middleware-usage) for additional info.

Comment: Thanks! It was definitely the ordering. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score -2):

You can always create your own middleware for Faraday.

```
require 'faraday'

class RequestFormatterMiddleware < Faraday::Middleware
  def call(env)
    env = format_body(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def format_body(env)
    env.body = 'test' #here is any of needed operation
    env
  end
end

conn = Faraday.new("http://localhost") do |c|
  c.use RequestFormatterMiddleware
end

response = conn.post do |req|
 req.url "http://localhost"
 req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
 req.body = '{ "name": "lalalal" }' 
end

p response.body #=> "test"
```

Comment: Why did you vote down? With own middleware you can do serialisation easily.

Comment: I down voted because this was a bad solution. @I'L'I's comment is the correct solution. The advice of writing custom middleware to fix a parameter ordering issue (which was the only problem) is absurd.